# Prevent CopyQ clipboard manager from keeping data from KeePass

Tags: clipboard, keepass

I use [CopyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) clipboard manager, but I don't want it to keep data from  [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) password manager for security reasons.
How can I set up CopyQ for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

copyq allows to prevent the storage of data based on the title on the originating window.

Open commands dialog with F6, click "Add" button, select 'Ignore *"Password"* window' and then change the "Window" text field in the new command to match a window title to ignore.

Keepass window has for title "[name of your database].kdbx - Keepass". We will then search for the pattern "ends with '- Keepass'" or ("- Keepass$" using regex notation).
[image]

[Source](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/278)

Comment: in the Window section *KeePass* only is fine now.  Copyq checks for the partial strings too.